# SSRS Report has a tablix with see through fixed header row

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services

I have a SSRS Report that has a tablix (location is 0cm, 0cm) with a fixed header row, all columns have a set background colour. Note when I say all I actually have 2 header rows the first row is title and the 2nd row is normal column header rows. Also the first row has a merged column across 12 columns and thus a rectangle and an image in one of the columns, rest are default textboxes no text) yet when I scroll I can still see text (as in data from the detail area) through gaps of my header in the very top and bottom pixel row, and a few pixels below the image. Can I put this down to a browser (IE) or a SSRS issue that does not have a solution - in other words it is a dimension rounding issue say cm's vs inches vs pixels to the 5th decimal point if you get my drift?

Note I did try Chrome and I got no data at all.
Also tried in Edge but edge does not respected fixed rows nor the parameter panel for that matter, you got to love Microsoft.

Looks like I might have to experiment with setting all my rows to less decimal points to see if it fixes it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was almost correct, I set my row heights to at minimal to 1 decimal point, row 1 is 1.4cm and row 2 0.9cm and that did the trick for the overlapping/traling pixels at the bottom of the header, also cut the placed the image into rectangle first and set the background of the rectangle to white that fixed the hole in the image, image size is FitProportional. Still having an issue with the top row of trailing pixels and this across the entire tablix (like beyond the image) not just what you see in the screenshot I posted. So I am still open for ideas to the get triple strike jack prize.

Comment: I've had similar issues that had to do with the "Padding" properties of the textboxes.  You may want to set that property to 1px on all sides to prevent weird overlap like that.

Comment: I assume you mean pt (px is not a valid unit designator) it is SSRS remember not html anyhow the default is 2pt, I tried 0pt on all my textboxes. A rectangle has no such setting but the image was 0pt however; it did not make any difference. I take from this reading between the lines that I wont have an issue if my top rows was all textboxes. I will have to play around